# Calling Deezer API using Ajax (jquery) - dataType JSON return null - JSONP return error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, deezer

here is my code, i suggest you to test it :

```
           function callDeezerAPI() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://api.deezer.com/playlist/580739065',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
            callDeezerAPI();
```

I'm just trying to get the same result as if I'go to http://api.deezer.com/playlist/580739065 and works with these JSON data.

When I use JSONP dataType, I can see the data I want through a JQuery error... so I can't use it.

Please let me know if someone knows how to do this using JSON or JSONP (it seems that Deezer API accepts JSONP...).

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify the format via the output-parameter:

```
http://api.deezer.com/playlist/580739065?output=jsonp
```